# Including Map Fragment not working in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-maps-android-api-2

I am trying to get a map on a fragment view in my android application. The app is crashing when trying to open this view. Until now, I did manage to have the same view working with an activity, but I need to have it in a fragment.

This is the fragment class:

```
public class NearMapFragment extends Fragment {

    private GoogleMap theMap;
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private int shopIcon;
    private Marker vitalis;
    private Marker siege;
    private ImageButton close;

    public NearMapFragment(){}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_near_map, container, false);

        // Check status of Google Play Services
        int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getActivity());

        // Check Google Play Service Available
        try {
            if (status != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error: GooglePlayServiceUtil: ", "" + e);
        }




                shopIcon = R.drawable.icoadresse;

                if(theMap==null){
                    //map not instantiated yet
                }
                theMap = ((MapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.the_map)).getMap();
                if(theMap != null){
                    //ok - proceed
                }
                theMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
                updatePlaces();
                return rootView;
    }       


    private void updatePlaces(){

        double lat = 46.581256;
        double lon = 0.379868;
        String name = "Position 1";
        String address = "Poitiers";
        LatLng POS1 = new LatLng(lat, lon); 
        siege = theMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(VITALIS_SIEGE)
        .title(name)
        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(shopIcon))
        .snippet(address));

        double lat2 = 46.580862;
        double lon2 = 0.341258;
        String name2 = "Position 2";
        String address2 = "Poitiers";
        LatLng POS2 = new LatLng(lat2, lon2); 
        vitalis = theMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(POS2)
        .title(name2)
        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(shopIcon))
        .snippet(address2));

    theMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(46.574826, 0.352488), 13.0f), 400, null); 
    }


}
```

And the log:

```
02-24 09:19:41.596: E/AndroidRuntime(4959): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
02-24 09:19:41.596: E/AndroidRuntime(4959):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
02-24 09:19:41.596: E/AndroidRuntime(4959):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:816)
02-24 09:19:41.596: E/AndroidRuntime(4959):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:745)
02-24 09:19:41.596: E/AndroidRuntime(4959):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
02-24 09:19:41.596: E/AndroidRuntime(4959):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
02-24 09:19:41.596: E/AndroidRuntime(4959):     at com.begital.vitalis.NearMapFragment.onCreateView(NearMapFragment.java:36)
02-24 09:19:41.596: E/AndroidRuntime(4959):     at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1700)
02-24 09:19:41.596: E/AndroidRuntime(4959):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:890)
02-24 09:19:41.596: E/AndroidRuntime(4959):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
02-24 09:19:41.596: E/AndroidRuntime(4959):     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:684)
02-24 09:19:41.596: E/AndroidRuntime(4959):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1447)
02-24 09:19:41.596: E/AndroidRuntime(4959):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:443)
02-24 09:19:41.596: E/AndroidRuntime(4959):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
02-24 09:19:41.596: E/AndroidRuntime(4959):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
02-24 09:19:41.596: E/AndroidRuntime(4959):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-24 09:19:41.596: E/AndroidRuntime(4959):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
02-24 09:19:41.596: E/AndroidRuntime(4959):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-24 09:19:41.596: E/AndroidRuntime(4959):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-24 09:19:41.596: E/AndroidRuntime(4959):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
02-24 09:19:41.596: E/AndroidRuntime(4959):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
02-24 09:19:41.596: E/AndroidRuntime(4959):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-24 09:19:41.596: E/AndroidRuntime(4959): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment cannot be cast to android.support.v4.app.Fragment
02-24 09:19:41.596: E/AndroidRuntime(4959):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:402)
02-24 09:19:41.596: E/AndroidRuntime(4959):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:377)
02-24 09:19:41.596: E/AndroidRuntime(4959):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:277)
02-24 09:19:41.596: E/AndroidRuntime(4959):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
  theMap = ((MapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.the_map)).getMap();
```

to

```
 theMap  = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.the_map)).getMap();
```

Also in xml
change

```
 android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
```

to

```
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
```

and extend your class with

```
public class NearMapFragment extends FragmentActivity{
 }
```

Comment: Not working because Method getSupportFragmentManager() is not supported by this class.

Comment: So why don't you extend activity from FragmentActivity instead of Fragment

Comment: I want to have this work as fragment because I need it this way (I'm using a menu that requires fragments)

Comment: Can you post your fragment tag from your xml?

Comment: <include
    android:id="@+id/the_map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"

Comment: and the map itself: <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://scheams.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/the_map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"

Comment: change android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" to  class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment". and it will work, but for this you have to extend activity by FragmentActivity

Comment: What do you mean by to extend activity by FragmentActivity and I can't replace the name by class in the xml

Comment: @user88 I did what you said but error on this line: int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getActivity());

Comment: change getActivity() to NearMapFragment.this or simply this

Answer (score 0):

problem is at this line

```
     View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_near_map, container, false);
```

use

```
   container = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_near_map, null);
```

Comment: Done but cause NPE on this line: theMap = ((MapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.the_map)).getMap();